# Trying to run alter session command to set session variable through JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, session, jdbc

I am trying to run an alter system command through JDBC which is required for me to run a query optimally.

I`m not sure if I am doing it right as I am not able to see the effect of the alter session statement. How do we persist the same session in JDBC what I mean is if I use the same connection and not close it does it mean I am using the same session?
The connection and database class are just helper classes to get a connection.

```
MyConnection mainDatabaseConnection = new MyConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@aas:111:"+tm.databaseName, "sys as sysdba", "xxx");
        Database mainDatabase = new Database(mainDatabaseConnection.getConnection());

        /* Fill in with data got for the main database */
        //String auditQuery = mainDatabase.generateAuditQuery(tm.schemaName, tm.tableName);
        String auditQuery = "select id, name, school, start, end from user where start>'11-11-11' and start<'12-12-12'";
        System.out.println(auditQuery);
        ResultSet rs = mainDatabase.runQuery("ALTER SESSION set optimizer_use_invisible_indexes = true");
//        ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
//        System.out.println(md.getColumnCount());
        rs.close();
    mainDatabase.close();
    mainDatabaseConnection.close();
```

I am not sure if the alter session command ran successfully.

Question 2: When I run a Select query using Statement I get a resultSet. WHen I close the statement does the resultSet get closed too? So, as soon as I close the statment or connection does all the fetched data go away?

Comment: Please restrict yourself to one question per question.

Comment: Ok. I`ll do that from now on.

Answer (score 3):

A `java.sql.Connection` object represents a session in Oracle. As long as you keep using the same object, you're in the same session.

With regard to closing `Statement`s, as Mark Rotteveel commented - closing a `Statement` will indeed close a `ResultSet` that was opened by it. It would, however, be recommended to close the `RestulSet` once you're done with it, even (or, actually - especially) if you intend to reuse the `Statement` object.

Comment: And what about the Alter session statement. Should I be using statment.executeUpdate() method for it and how do I make sure it went through fine for that session? Thanks for the prompt reply @Mureinik

Comment: @ramu This isn't a query, so yes, you should definitely be using `executeUpdate()`. Wrt "how do I make sure it went through fine for that session?" - I do not understand what you're asking. Could you plesae clarify?

Comment: The JDBC specification does require that closing the statement closes the result set. [`Statement.close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close--) documents this _**Note**:When a Statement object is closed, its current ResultSet object, if one exists, is also closed._ It is also documented in section 13.1.4 of JDBC 4.2 (_Closing a Statement object will close and invalidate any instances of ResultSet produced by that Statement object._)

Comment: 1. I mean how to check if the executeUpdate went fine and did set the session variable? 2.So if I want to have some computation on the resultSet I shouldn`t close the statement or the connection right.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have a vague recollection of a problem with dangling open cursors in such a situation with a proprietary driver I used in the past, but it was probably a faulty implementation of `Statement.close()`. Many thanks for the correction. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @ramu 1. If the `executeUpdate` call fails, it will throw an `SQLException`. If it doesn't, it succeeded. 2. Indeed.

Comment: stmt.executeUpdate(query); Worked :)